# Generate grid neighborhood as prerequisites in Makefile

Tags: makefile

I am trying to (ab)use a Makefile to describe a process of data generation. My data are a raster data mosaic tiles covering the world, in chunks of 30°×20° (longitude×latitude), where the tile labels are derived from the GMTED names:

```
lat := 70S 50S 30S 10S 10N 30N 50N 70N
lon := 180W 150W 120W 090W 060W 030W 000E 030E 060E 090E 120E 150E

tiles := $(foreach LAT,$(lat),$(foreach LON,$(lon),$(LAT)$(LON)))
```

For some step in the computation, each tile and its 8 neighbors are needed. So for example, one rule is

```
distances-extended-50S180W.tif: distances-50S180W.tif distances-70S150W.tif distances-70S150E.tif distances-50S150W.tif distances-50S150E.tif distances-30S150W.tif distances-30S150E.tif distances-70S180W.tif distances-30S180W.tif
    python extend 50S180W
```

(so the `lon`s wrap, but for the `lat`s, the extremes have just 6 instead of 9 prerequisites.) How can I make this more concise than generating all these 96 rules externally and including them into the makefile?

Comment: A bit unfair to let such elaborate answers linger around unaccepted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's worth the effort but if you use GNU make a slightly simpler and less error prone solution than the full enumeration could be something like:

```
##################
# utility macros #
##################

# cross-product of two lists; $1: first list; $2: second list
define xp
$(sort $(foreach a,$1,$(foreach b,$2,$a$b)))
endef

#############
# variables #
#############

lat  :=  70S  70S  50S  30S  10S  10N  30N  50N  70N  70N
ilat :=         2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
lon  := 150E 180W 150W 120W 090W 060W 030W 000E 030E 060E 090E 120E 150E 180W
ilon :=         2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13

# compute north (n-LAT), central (c-LAT) and south (s-LAT) of all latitudes; $1: integer latitude
define ncs
n-$1 := $$(word $$(shell expr $1 + 1),$(lat))
c-$1 := $$(word $1,$(lat))
s-$1 := $$(word $$(shell expr $1 - 1),$(lat))
endef
$(foreach l,$(ilat),$(eval $(call ncs,$l)))

# compute west (w-LON), middle (m-LON) and east (e-LON) of all longitudes; $1: interger longitude
define wme
w-$1 := $$(word $$(shell expr $1 - 1),$(lon))
m-$1 := $$(word $1,$(lon))
e-$1 := $$(word $$(shell expr $1 + 1),$(lon))
endef
$(foreach l,$(ilon),$(eval $(call wme,$l)))

# instantiate tile rule; $1: integer latitude, $2: integer longitude
define tile-rule
$1-$2-point := $$(c-$1)$$(m-$2)

$1-$2-prereq := $$(call xp,$$(n-$1) $$(c-$1) $$(s-$1),$$(w-$2) $$(m-$2) $$(e-$2))

distances-extended-$$($1-$2-point).tif: $$(patsubst %,distances-%.tif,$$($1-$2-prereq))
    python extend $$($1-$2-point)
endef
$(foreach la,$(ilat),$(foreach lo,$(ilon),$(eval $(call tile-rule,$(la),$(lo)))))
```

Latitudes and longitudes are represented not only as labels but also as integers (variables `ilat` and `ilon`), which simplifies the computation of north, south, west and east of positions.

The `word` function is used to convert integers to labels.

The saturation of latitudes (north of `70N` is `70N` and south of `70S` is `70S`) are guaranteed by left and right extensions of the `lat` variable and by the bounds of the `ilat` variable. Same for the wrapping of longitudes with the extended `lon` variable and the bounds of the `ilon` variable.

The `tile-rule` macro instantiates all rules. The only subtlety here is the use of the `sort` function in the `xp` macro. It sorts but also removes duplicates (for extremes).

Demo with a modified `tile-rule` macro to create the files and print the instantiated rules:

```
$ cat Makefile
...
.PHONY: all clean

# instantiate tile rule; $1: integer latitude, $2: integer longitude
define tile-rule
$1-$2-point := $$(c-$1)$$(m-$2)

distances-$$($1-$2-point).tif:
    @touch "$$@"

$1-$2-prereq := $$(call xp,$$(n-$1) $$(c-$1) $$(s-$1),$$(w-$2) $$(m-$2) $$(e-$2))

distances-extended-$$($1-$2-point).tif: $$(patsubst %,distances-%.tif,$$($1-$2-prereq))
    @printf '%s:' "$$@"
    @printf ' %s' "$$^"
    @printf '\n\tpython extend $$($1-$2-point)\n'
    @touch "$$@"

all: distances-extended-$$($1-$2-point).tif

clean::
    @rm -f distances-$$($1-$2-point).tif distances-extended-$$($1-$2-point).tif
endef
$(foreach la,$(ilat),$(foreach lo,$(ilon),$(eval $(call tile-rule,$(la),$(lo)))))

$ make clean
$ make -j1 all
make -j1 all
distances-extended-70S180W.tif: distances-50S150E.tif distances-50S150W.tif distances-50S180W.tif distances-70S150E.tif distances-70S150W.tif distances-70S180W.tif
    python extend 70S180W
...
distances-extended-50S180W.tif: distances-30S150E.tif distances-30S150W.tif distances-30S180W.tif distances-50S150E.tif distances-50S150W.tif distances-50S180W.tif distances-70S150E.tif distances-70S150W.tif distances-70S180W.tif
    python extend 50S180W
...
```

Comment: Is `zip` throwing doublets away on purpose - the reason you didn't `join`?

Comment: Yes, `zip` throws doublets away on purpose such that extremes have only 6 prerequisites instead of 9, as asked by the OP. I did not use `join` because it ... joins. I agree that `zip` is not the best possible name for what it does (cross-product). I'll edit and change it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list-oriented method:

```
lat := southpole 70S 50S 30S 10S 10N 30N 50N 70N northpole
lon := 180W 150W 120W 090W 060W 030W 000E 030E 060E 090E 120E 150E

# rotate-repeat(list,n,len):
#    do "n" times: output the first "len" elements of "list", then rotate "list" one left
# "list" must be >= "len"
rotate-repeat = $(if $2,$(wordlist 1,$3,$1) $(call rotate-repeat,$(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1) $(firstword $1),$(wordlist 2,1000,$2),$3))

# create repeated list of latitudes (including poles)
lat_ := $(foreach _,$(lon),$(lat))
# create repeated and shifted list of longitudes
lon_ := $(call rotate-repeat,$(lon),$(lon),$(words $(lat)))

# triple-cartprod(list1,list2,func)
# create the cartesian product of the two leading triples in the given
# lists and call func with them, then recurse until lists empty
triple-cartprod = $(call $3,\
$(word 1,$1)$(word 1,$2) $(word 2,$1)$(word 1,$2) $(word 3,$1)$(word 1,$2) \
$(word 1,$1)$(word 2,$2) $(word 2,$1)$(word 2,$2) $(word 3,$1)$(word 2,$2) \
$(word 1,$1)$(word 3,$2) $(word 2,$1)$(word 3,$2) $(word 3,$1)$(word 3,$2)) \
$(if $(word 4,$1),$(call triple-cartprod,$(wordlist 2,1000,$1),$(wordlist 2,1000,$2),$3))

# how to make a rule: we throw away rules for the poles and filter
# them out from the prereqs
make-rule = $(if $(findstring pole,$(word 5,$1)),,$(info $(word 5,$1) : $(filter-out %pole,$(wordlist 1,4,$1) $(wordlist 6,9,$1))))

# main:
$(call triple-cartprod,$(lon_),$(lat_),make-rule)
```